# Dynamic Timeline with Graph

Tags: filter, jquery, timeline

I like Yahoo Finance Stock Chart, and the way you can filter by a date range:

[image: Finance Graph]

I have a database of news headlines, and I'd like to replace our date filter, especially for the tag cloud, with some sort of dynamic range widget.  I think most of our users are going to want to see headlines and tags from the most recent X days, so I could just use a regular slider, but the idea of being able to slide both the timeline length (3 months) and range (Sept '04 - Nov '04') seems pretty cool.  Specifically, with the cloud tag you could visually represent which tags were popular during one particular time.  Like "trending".

Finally, adding volume (headline count) like the stock chart volume could be interesting as well.

My question: Are there any javascript libraries / server libraries that do something like this already?  Maybe with Google Charts?  Or some jquery / jqueryui tool?  We're using Bootstrap during development.  I'd like to avoid Flash.

Thx,

Tac

Comment: Hi @Tac JQuery library requests aren't really the type of questions we should be helping you with, this one in particular is a bit too much like a 'Can I get a shopping recomendation' type query. What solutions have you already tried and why didn't they suit your requirements? If you're able to get more specific about the requirements and have exhausted your research then *perhaps* the chaps at programmers.stackexchange.com would be able to help you, although in it's current form this question would just be closed by the mods there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are 2 javascript libraries that 
can mimic your finance graph image.

Highcharts - http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/

amCharts - http://www.amcharts.com/stock/

There is also an interesting jQuery plugin date range slider
called jQRangeSlider - http://ghusse.github.com/jQRangeSlider/stable/demo/, 
although adding any kind of volume trending to it would be more work.

As an aside, here's at least one article that questions the usability 
of tag-clouds. http://www.useit.com/alertbox/tag-clouds.html